# Selenium: Scraping All Element Attributes via Javascript Returns Incorrect Results

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm scraping all element attributes via javascript using the following code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value}; return items;", element);
```

Although this *mostly* returns only the attributes that identify the element in question I'm finding certain attributes are returned by this code that do not actually correspond to the desired element.

*Case in point:*

If you navigate to http://google.com and identify the search box via `(.//input[contains (@role,'combobox')])` (or any one of many other XPath) and then execute said JS code it returns the attribute `(.//input[contains (@class,'gsfi lst-d-f')])` that does not actually correspond with the search box. In fact, this attribute is not even present on page when using FireBug.

I did notice though that a similar text is hidden in the style tag on page however even there I did not find an exact match of this text. In either case it still does not correspond to the element in question.

Why does JS return this text and is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: It's working fine for me. My guess is that your locator is not specific enough and is picking up an element other than the search box. The search box has an id, `lst-ib`, why don't you just use that?